# Fetch Username and Password for Authentication

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, authentication

I try to authenticate user by matching username and password input with database. The password is SHA1. Here's the related code :

```
public function init()
{
    $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
    $this->db = $bootstrap->getResource('auth');
    $this->session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('login');
    if(isset($this->session->isLogin)){
        $this->_helper->redirector('/guestbook');
    }
}

public function validAction()
{
    if(!isset($this->session->isLogin)){
        $username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        $login = $this->loginLocal($username, $password);
        if($login['username']!=''){
            echo '{success:true, result:{message:\'Welcome, '.$username.'!\'}}';
        } else {
            echo '{success:false, errors:{reason:\'Login failed, try again.\'}}';
        }
    }
}

private function loginLocal($username, $password) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = SHA1('".$password."')";

    $fetch = $this->db->query($sql);
    $login = $fetch->fetch();

    return $login;
}
```

But it's not working, with thrown error "Call to a member function query() on a non-object". Is this query error or what, I haven't figured it out. Any help appreciated, thank you.

**UPDATE :**

Here I add init function and validAction function. I am using Zend Framework on Netbeans. Indeed, $this->db is NULL, so how we can initialize it? Thank you.

Comment: Post the whole class or code block, what's inside $this->db, it seems somehow $this->db it's not initialized with the PDO driver

Comment: Are you sure `$this->db` has been initialized? Try running `var_dump($this->db)`.

Comment: The error is telling what is wrong.  It is not a query error, it is saying you are trying to execute the `query()` function on something that isn't object.  Essentially meaning that `$this->db` is not an object, which as @MicSokoli mentions, which means it hasn't been initialized.

Comment: @MicSokoli you're right sir, it shows NULL. So how I can initialize it?

Comment: You have to initialize database like $db=new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$databaseName) or die("Database error :".$db->error); Then your query should  be $fetch = $db->query($sql);

Comment: I think for Zend Framework the initialization using a different approach, but I haven't found it yet. @user3526204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database connection is not initialized

Do it like this

```
$db=new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$databaseName) or die("Database error :".$db->error);
```

Then your query should be

```
$fetch = $db->query($sql);
```